# Get file name relative to projectile root

Tags: files, projectile

I am trying to write a little function to get the `projectile` relative path of a buffer. My idea is to delete the substring `projectile-project-root` from the string `buffer-file-name`.

For example:

```
root-file-path: ~/src/dotfiles
buffer-file-name: ~/src/dotfiles/emacs.d/conf.org
relative-file-name: emacs.d/conf.org
```

my current code is this:

```el
(setq buffer-file-name (string-remove-prefix projectile-project-root
                                             buffer-file-name))
```

but I can't get it working. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you detail what isn't working? Looking at your code, you have at least two issues: you are quoting your call to `string-remove-prefix`, and `kill-new` should probably be called with only one argument

Comment: The step to generate the buffer relative file path, sorry I was trying in the eval buffer and didn't test the function. I will fix the question.

Comment: `buffer-file-name` must be an absolute, not relative, file name. If you want to change the buffer's user-visible name you should use `rename-buffer` instead. See [`(elisp) Buffer Names`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html). If that is not what you're trying to do, then please elaborate on what your ultimate goal is, as it's not very clear from your question.

Comment: I wnat to get the file path relative to the current project, to put it in the clipboard @Basil it was I said at the beggining of the question.

Comment: @rafaelleru Your question makes no mention of the kill ring or clipboard, but thanks for clarifying.

Comment: because my problem is with the file path, I already have other functions similar so I can copy in the clipboard and everithing else but I can't get the correct path.

Comment: @rafaelleru That is the kind of detail that would help make your question clearer. As things currently stand, the reader does not know what you're trying to achieve, or what you've tried so far, or why or how it isn't working.

Comment: OK @basil I will update the question with more context. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I think the reason your code is not working as hoped for is because you are using the buffer-local variable `projectile-project-root` instead of the eponymous function.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`projectile-project-root`<kbd>RET</kbd> reveals:

```
projectile-project-root is a variable defined in ‘projectile.el’.
Its value is nil

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

Documentation:
Defines a custom Projectile project root.
This is intended to be used as a file local variable.
```

In other words, `projectile.el` never sets this variable itself; it is provided only in case users want to set it buffer- or file-locally (see [`(emacs) Locals`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Locals.html) and [`(emacs) File Variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html), respectively).

This explains why

```el
(file-relative-name buffer-file-name projectile-project-root)
```

(which you mentioned in a [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45419/get-relative-path-of-file-in-projectile?noredirect=1#comment69835_45421)) returns the non-directory part of `buffer-file-name`, as opposed to the desired relative path.

Compare this with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`projectile-project-root`<kbd>RET</kbd>:

```
projectile-project-root is a compiled Lisp function in
‘projectile.el’.

(projectile-project-root &optional DIR)

Retrieves the root directory of a project if available.
If DIR is not supplied its set to the current directory by default.
```

Combining this knowledge with dakra's good [suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/45421/15748) to use `file-relative-name` instead of manipulating file names as strings (which should and almost always can be avoided), we arrive at the following means of [killing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing.html) the current buffer's absolute file name relative to its `projectile` root:

```el
(kill-new (file-relative-name buffer-file-name (projectile-project-root)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `file-relative-name`:

```
(file-relative-name "~/src/dotfiles/emacs.d/conf.org" "~/src/dotfiles")
"emacs.d/conf.org"
```

Comment: when I run as (file-relative-name buffer-file-name projectile-project-root) it returns only the buffer file name `conf.org` and not the relative path.