# Auto insert include guard in cpp header when inside projectile project

Tags: spacemacs, projectile, c++, auto-insert, file-header

I am currently learning C++ and I came across include guards to avoid double inclusion.

Now I would like to use the [google's style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#The__define_Guard) convention like this :

```
// project/src/app.hpp

#ifndef PROJECT_SRC_APP_HPP_
#define PROJECT_SRC_APP_HPP_
...
#endif  // PROJECT_SRC_APP_HPP_
```

and also

```
// project/src/util/test.hpp

#ifndef PROJECT_SRC_UTIL_TEST_HPP_
#define PROJECT_SRC_UTIL_TEST_HPP_
...
#endif  // PROJECT_SRC_UTIL_TEST_HPP_
```

So the macro name is basically the path of the header file in the current project.

My goal is to automate this task of writing the include guards each time I create a new `.hpp` file.
I looked at the [emacs auto insert mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode) which looks adapted to the situation but the question is the following :

I am using projectile so how can I get the full path from the root directory of the current project to construct the macro name?

Can anyone point me into the right direction? (btw I am using spacemacs)

Comment: Yes, there is a function called `projectile-project-root` which tell you the projectile workspace root directory, about the second question seems like for that task you could use [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) it's a template system quite easy and useful. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you so much! It's the kind of answer that I was waiting for :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to f-sasa, I was able to write my own yasnippet file in order to construct the include guard. With the help of [this yasnippet example](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#orgcde188c) and also [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45419/get-file-name-relative-to-projectile-root) about getting the projectile file path :

```
# key: include_guard
# name: C++ auto header include guard in project
# --

#ifndef ${1:`(upcase
              (concat
               (projectile-project-name)
               "_"
               (subst-char-in-string ?/ ?_
                                     (file-relative-name
                                      (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name)
                                      (projectile-project-root)))))`_HPP_}
#define $1

$0

#endif /* $1 */
```